# PyMongo - Find a document containing a unique key and delete that key and its contents

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a collection that contains many documents in which one may or may not contain a unique key that needs to be deleted:

Example:

```
DOC-X{
    OBJ1{},
    OBJ2{
        unique12: {},
        unique34: {},
        unique56: {},
    },
    OBJ3{}
}
```

How would I go about deleting only unique34 from OBJ2 in the document named DOC-X in python?
It is unknown if this object even exists but if it does it needs to be deleted.
This is an object within an object and not an array.

I have tried:

```
    coll = database["COLLECTION"]
    toDelete = "unique34"
    coll.find_one_and_delete({["OBJ2"][toDelete]: 1})
```

with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [$unset operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/)

Try:

```py
coll.update_one({}, {"$unset": {"DOC-X.OBJ2.unique34": ""}})
```

Results:

```
Before
{'DOC-X': {'OBJ1': {},
           'OBJ2': {'unique12': {}, 'unique34': {}, 'unique56': {}},
           'OBJ3': {}},
 '_id': ObjectId('5eb31a54ce9c5701ce4ef7fd')}
After
{'DOC-X': {'OBJ1': {}, 'OBJ2': {'unique12': {}, 'unique56': {}}, 'OBJ3': {}},
 '_id': ObjectId('5eb31a54ce9c5701ce4ef7fd')}
```